# How to use IconFinder API to GET Iconsets using authorized access Token in Ajax

Tags: javascript, api

I registered my application on `iconFinder` and use its JSON Web Token authentication to get access token and then use that token for authentication but it's not working.

I use another Ajax Get call to call its api using authorized access token then it return response (UNAUTHORIZED)

For Access Token:

```
var nf_token_url = "https://www.iconfinder.com/api/v3/oauth2/token";
const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";

var form = {
    "grant_type": "jwt_bearer",
    "client_id": "<*>",
    "client_secret": "<*>"
};

var formBody = [];
for (var property in form) {
    var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
    var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(form[property]);
    formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
}
formBody = formBody.join("&");

$.ajax({
    url: proxyurl + nf_token_url,
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'
    },
    data: formBody,
    type: 'post',
    datatype: "jsonp",
    success: function (response) {
        localStorage.setItem('IFT', response.access_token);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

});


  FOR Get Request Iconsets APi:

  $.ajax({
        url: proxyurl 
        +"https://api.iconfinder.com/v3/icons/searchquery=hello&count=30",
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
        beforeSend: function (request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokken);
        }

    });
```

Getting Error in Response :

```
{
    "message": "Unauthorized - client_id or client_secret not found",
    "code": "unauthorized"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I also got this error. Mine was resolved by adding client and secret in ajax call

```
       $.ajax({
            url: proxyurl +"https://api.iconfinder.com/v3/icons/search?query=hello&count=30",
            type: 'GET',
            data:  {
                "grant_type": "jwt_bearer",
                "client_id": "Your Id",
                "client_secret": "Your Secret"
            },
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            },
            beforeSend: function (request) {
                request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokken);
            }

        });
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working... i got data in response now..you solved my problem buddy !!! Thanks once again. :)

Comment: It's my pleasure buddy